# Add ajax response to mdl card

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, django

I want to do website with updating content from ajax request. I receive json data and i have to put this json data to MDL CARD. http://www.getmdl.io/components/index.html#cards-section

my ajax code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    displayRecords(limit, offset);
    $('#button').click(function (){
        limit = limit + 2;
        offset = offset + 2;
        displayRecords(limit, offset);
    });
});
function displayRecords(lim, off){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/main/",
        data: {'limit': lim, 'offset': off},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            for (var post in data){
                $('.mdl-card__supporting-text').append(data[post].fields.title);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

and my django code:

```
def posts(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        offset = request.GET.get('offset')
        limit = request.GET.get('limit')
        all_posts = Post.objects.all()[offset:limit]
        data = serializers.serialize('json', all_posts, ensure_ascii=False)
        print data
        return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json; charset=utf8')
    else:
        return render(request, 'main.html')
```

Comment: Do you have any questions/problems?

Comment: yes, how i can do this? how i put json data to mdl card?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used mustache.js. It is helped me.

Comment: How did you use it? Can you give some examples?